# Transformation matrices in a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F=\mathbb{R}$,$X=\mathbb{R^3}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R^2}$. Further $B_X$ and $B_Y$ are given by:

$B_X:=\{(1,0,0),(1,0,-1),(1,-1,-1)\}$
$B_Y:=\{(1,0),(1,-1)\}$

Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ and [...] be given as:
$f(x,y,z)=(y,x-z,x+z)$ $x,y,z\in F$

Calculate the transformation matrix (ger: "Darstellungsmatrix") $A=M(f,B_X,B_X)$ and [...]

so i just plug in all vectors of $B_X$ in $f$ and see what i get?

$f(1,0,0)=(0,1,1)\\
f(1,0,-1)=(0,2,0)\\
f(1,-1,-1)=(-1,2,0)\\$

Giving me $A=\{(0,1,1),(0,2,0),(-1,2,0)\}$ (in Matrix-form)

Is this it already?

And what do i have to do when calculating $B=M(g,B_X,B_Y)$, while
$g(x,y,z)=(2x-2y,x+y)$ ? Do i just plugin $B_X$ in g, and see what i get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correcting your method:** You're almost there.  But you found the components of the image vectors *with respect to the standard basis* -- not $B_X$.  So now you just need to find the components of those three vectors with respect to (wrt) $B_X$.  For instance $(0,2,0) = 0(1,0,0)+2(1,0,-1)-2(1,-1,-1)$.  So the components of this vector wrt $B_X$ are $(0,2,-2)$.  This will then be the second column of your matrix.

---

**Transition matrix method:** Let $\mathcal E$ be the standard basis for $X$.  Then we know that $$f(x,y,z)=(y,x-z,x+z) \iff [f]_{\mathcal E\leftarrow \mathcal E} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1}$$

Now we construct the transition matrix $I_{\mathcal E \leftarrow B_X}$.

Luckily we're already given the components of the elements of $B_X$ in terms of $\mathcal E$.  So

$$I_{\mathcal E \leftarrow B_X} = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & -1}$$

Then to find $I_{B_X \leftarrow \mathcal E}$, we simply find the inverse of this matrix:

$$I_{B_X \leftarrow \mathcal E} = {I_{\mathcal E \leftarrow B_X}}^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0}$$

Then to find $[f]_{B_X \leftarrow B_X}$ we just multiply:

$$[f]_{B_X \leftarrow B_X} = I_{B_X \leftarrow \mathcal E}[f]_{\mathcal E \leftarrow \mathcal E}I_{\mathcal E \leftarrow B_X} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ -1 & -2 & -2}$$

---

You can use a similar approach to find $[g]_{B_Y\leftarrow B_X}$ by multiplying out:

$$[g]_{B_Y\leftarrow B_X} = I_{B_Y \leftarrow \mathcal E_2}[g]_{\mathcal E_2\leftarrow \mathcal E_3}I_{\mathcal E_3 \leftarrow B_X}$$

where $\mathcal E_2$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and $\mathcal E_3$ is th standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Hi, i had a different approach, can you tell me if this is "technicly" right too? $f(1,0,0)=(0,1,1)=1*(1,0,0)+0*(1,0,-1)+(-1)*(1,-1,-1)$\\
$f(1,0,-1)=(0,2,0)=0*(1,0,0)+2*(1,0,-1)+(-2)*(1,-1,-1)$\\
$f(1,-1,-1)=(-1,2,0)=(-1)*(1,0,0)+2*(1,0,-1)+(-2)*(1,-1,-1)$\\
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 2  \\
-1 & -2 & -2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$ we both got the same result, but i dont really understand for what this is good :( (by different appr. i mean: i got no f*ng clue what i did, but strangely enough i got what you got)

Comment: That is correct as well -- see my edit.  It works because you're essentially just doing the conversions that the matrices $I_{\mathcal E\leftarrow B_X}$ and $I_{B_X\leftarrow \mathcal E}$ do by hand.  There's nothing wrong with that method and in fact in this case it's probably faster.

Comment: Hi, thanks man, can you look on this and tell me if its correct? $g(1,0,0)=(2,1)=3*(1,0)+(-1)*(1,-1)$\\
$g(1,0,-1)=(2,1)=3*(1,0)+(-1)*(1,-1)$\\
$g(1,-1,-1)=(4,0)=4*(1,0)+0*(1,-1)$\\
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
3 & -1 \\
4 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ or should the result be a matrix with height of 2?

Comment: You have the transpose of the correct matrix.  As a quick way to check the dimensions note that $g$ eats vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ so $[g]$ should have $3$ columns for matrix multiplication with a $3\times 1$ matrix to work.

Comment: Ok, now, the assignment is also to: caclulate B*A (which is easy for a calculator, and i can that already), but more importantly: "show that $BA=M(g\circ f,B_X,B_Y)$ " how do i "$\circ$" two functions correctly? do i put $B_X$ in $g$, and then the result in $f$?

Comment: $(g\circ f)(x,y,z) = g(f(x,y,z)) = g(y,x-z,x+z)$.  Construct a matrix for this from basis $B_X$ to basis $B_Y$ and then check that it's the same as the one you get by multiplying $BA$.

Comment: $BA=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3 & 4\\
-1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 2  \\
-1 & -2 & -2  \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -5\\
-1 & -2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$\\\\\\
$H:=M(g\circ f,B_X,B_Y)=M(g(f),B_X,B_Y)$\\
$g(f)=g(y,x-z,x+z)=(2y-2(x-z),y+(x-z))\\
=(2y-2x+2z,y+x-z)=(-2x+2y+2z,x+y-z)$\\
$h:=g(f)=(-2x+2y+2z,x+y-z)$\\
$h(1,0,0)=(-2,1)=(-1)*(1,0)+(-1)*(1,-1)$\\
$h(1,0,-1)=(-4,2)=(-2)*(1,0)+(-2)*(1,-1)$\\
$h(1,-1,-1)=(-6,1)=(-5)*(1,0)+(-1)*(1,-1)$\\
$H=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -5\\
-1 & -2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}=BA$ ok?

Comment: If you got the same answer both ways then it should be good.